# Java Android ImageView-Image rotation only works for the first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview, image-rotation

I have written java-android code for image view that will rotate and fade away and another image will be visible, I use `imageViewer.animate.rotation(3600).alpha(0);` now this works fine when I run the code on an emulator, the images fade and re-appear just fine, but the problem is about the rotation after I compile the app for the first time when I click on the image, it will rotate and fade away and the next picture is shown, but when I tap on the image again, it will not rotate, instead only the fade in and fade out will work but not the rotation (Note that it rotates for the first time after compilation but then doesn't rotates and fade in/out works only). Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    boolean eggview = true;

    public void fade(View view)
    {
        ImageView eggImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
        ImageView chickImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chick);
        if (eggview)
        {
            eggview = false;
            eggImageView.animate().rotation(3600).setDuration(1200).alpha(0);
            chickImageView.animate().alpha(1);
        }
        else
        {
            eggview = true;
            chickImageView.animate().rotation(3600).alpha(0).setDuration(1200);
            eggImageView.animate().alpha(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: So You have 2 images. If You click You want one to rotate and fade and second to be shown? And when click again You want to the same?

Comment: Yes Exactly...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `rotation` to 0 when setting alpha to `1`. When You set `rotation` to `3600` it isn't `3600` degrees from the current state but from the default state, that's why it works only one time.

```
boolean eggview = true;
public void fade(View view)
{
    ImageView eggImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    ImageView chickImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chick);
    if (eggview)
    {
        eggview = false;
        eggImageView.animate().rotation(3600).setDuration(1200).alpha(0);
        chickImageView.animate().alpha(1).rotation(0);
    }
    else
    {
        eggview = true;
        chickImageView.animate().rotation(3600).alpha(0).setDuration(1200);
        eggImageView.animate().alpha(1).rotation(0);
    }
}
```

If You don't want to make a backward rotation when fading in just set rotation to `actual state + 3600`. But the main problem with Your code is setting rotation to the actual state.

Comment: works like a charm. i had been searching for this issue since days, but couldn't get it solved. At last i asked here and viola... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the

[ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#rotationBy(float))

method rotationBy() instead of rotation()

```
eggImageView.animate().rotationBy(3600)...
```

rotation() moves the View TO 360f and rotationBy() moves the View BY 360f

same with alphaBy()